# Custom Sortby , Order by issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I have data in table -> bp like below

```
1   Vendor  
2   Customer    
3   Transporter
```

I want `select * from bp order by row value 2,1,3`, like this the result should be:

```
2 Customer
1 Vendor
3 Transporter
```

Comment: use a case statement. `case ID when 2 then 1 when 1 then 2 when 3 then 3 else 4 end`.

Comment: It's easy to write an ORDER BY for this specific case. But what will happen if a row is added or deleted, or changed?

Comment: What is the basis for your ordering?

Comment: Please read carefully ...

Comment: The case expression that @xQbert posted is the way to do this unless there is some sort of criteria that can be used.

Answer (score 1):

As the ordering isn't alphabetic or numeric, and appears somewhat arbitrary, then use a case statement.  However this doesn't support growth and code would have to be changed anytime a new value is presented in col2.  You'd be better off including an orderBy Column in the base table containing these values. and allowing a user to specify order for long term usability.  Why tie a user into a specific order...  Seems odd but this is the way to do it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM bp 
order by CASE when col2='Customer' then 1 
              when col2='Vendor' then 2
              when col2='Transporter' then 3
              else then 4 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

Add One More Column SortBy and Add Values Like first digit shows one type of sort, second digit second type and third digit third type. Its a one and very simple way. If records are more then you can arrange it in other ways.

1    Vendor           132

2    Customer       213

3    Transporter     321

Vendor --> select * from bp order by substring(SortBy,1,1)
Customer --> select * from bp order by substring(SortBy,2,1)
Transporter --> select * from bp order by substring(SortBy,3,1)